# WPF: Do VS 2010 and Blend 4 really integrate well?

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF, so this is my first project.

I started with the coding side of things using VS. I am overall pretty satisfied with the way VS is used to build a WPF app, however a big part of WPF is also animation.

So to my relief, I was able to open the solution I created using VS 2010, in Expression Blend 4.

I opened it, but then I noticed the form design view in Blend 4. My heart sank. Please don't tell me WPF 4 is still so immature as a product that you cannot yet work decently with WPF projects created in VS 2010?

See the screen shots:

Here is good old VS 2010 form design view. As you can see there is a menu and a label control on the form.

[image]

Here on the other hand is the same form open in Blend 4:

As you can see, no design time support it seems for ANY existing elements. The form besides being black, seems to not contain my menu or label.

[image]

Have I done something wrong, or is Blend this immature?

My course of action seems to be learning the XAML and using pure VS 2010 for animation, but that means that Blend 4 would be a failed product in my eyes.

Update:

Here is the full screen , so this is after opening the MainWindow.xaml in Blend 4.
[image]

Comment: Window -> Projects. After that find the tab with tree (usually on the left) and open the file MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: If you save (CTRL-SHIFT-S) or build when you switch between VS and Blend I've found them to work together very well. Have you have saved your solution in VS? Perhaps blend is opening the empty project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well I figured it out.

I am guessing its also a bug in Blend 4.

In VS 2010 my Window visibility was initially hidden, this is because I have a custom splash screen which first loads, then sets the visibility to true.

So design mode imo of Blend should not pay attention to the Windows visibility property, this is a run time property really.

Setting the visibility to true of the form / window. and the results are better.

Comment: this isn't a bug, it done in purpose. In Blend, the visibility is applied in the designer mode, so you can see it.

Comment: Ok, having thought about it, it does make sense. I guess its just something people should be aware of.